# Calling ViewController's Method from App Delegate

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

Within my ViewController, Inbox, I'd like to call the method playAudio() from my App Delegate.

This is the method.

```
func playAudio(){

        let nowPlaying = MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter()

        let albumArtWork = MPMediaItemArtwork(image: UIImage(named: "testImage.jpg")!)

        nowPlaying.nowPlayingInfo = [MPMediaItemPropertyTitle:"Sonnnngggg",
            MPMediaItemPropertyArtist:"Arrrtttiiiissstttt",
            MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork:albumArtWork]
        audioPlayer.play()

    }
```

And I'd like to call it from my App Delegate...

```
if event!.subtype == UIEventSubtype.RemoteControlPlay {
                print("received remote play")
                //audioPlayer.play()
                Inbox.playAudio()
            }
```

The one problem is that because I have a audioPlayer and everything within my Inbox ViewController, and that it's probably already playing audio, it doesn't make sense to make an instance of Inbox to call playAudio().  So, please let me know if there are any workarounds in Swift.

Thanks,
Liam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AppDelegate change to:

```
if event!.subtype == UIEventSubtype.RemoteControlPlay {
            print("received remote play")
            //audioPlayer.play()
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("RemotePlayPressed", object: self)
        }
```

Then in Inbox view controller's viewDidLoad add:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "playAudio", name: "RemotePlayPressed", object: nil)
```

also add:

```
deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```

to Inbox view controller.

Answer (score 0):

in your viewcontroller you reach your appdelegate via

`(UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).playAudio()`

Comment: I'd like to call my ViewController's function via my app delegate.

Comment: It is nested within a Navigation Controller... It's the farthest branch. The function is just a normal function there are other methods too.

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate the AppDelegate and call the function you want

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.someFunction()
```

But it not seems to be a good pratice...

#### NSNotificationCenter:

Use this code in the place you want to call the function:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "anotherFunction", name: "SomeNotification", object: nil)
```

change **anotherFunction** to the function name you want to call.

On AppDelegate:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("SomeNotification", object: nil)
```

Comment: I'd like to call my ViewController's function via my app delegate.

Comment: You can work with NSNotificationCenter to achieve this.

Comment: Could you edit your answer to show this? I'm a a bit new.